# Creating Orchard module without commandline

Tags: orchardcms

How does one create a new Orchard Module scaffolding without having access to the commandline tool? It's not like every hosting package will give you RDP or other such remote access tools to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create modules in your running application. Create your module local on your dev computer, then publish it to your website.

Upload it in your Orchard website through:

1. FTP: upload your module through ftp directly in the /modules directory
2. Zip file:  Create a zip file from your module. Alter the extension to '.nupkg' (myModule.nupkg). Go to you application's module section -> upload from computer -> locate the zip file -> install.
3. Publish to gallery: Publish your module to the Orchard's module gallery, then install it through the gallery on your application (Only do this if you don't mind to share your module's functions. You shouldn't publish company specific stuff)

Comment: I'll do that. So I gather that there is no other way than the commandline? It's not a problem, but it just feels strange.

Comment: The command line allows you to **scaffold**, you can create your whole module by hand by just creating the files you need. If you are developing with VS you should checkout this extension: https://github.com/Hazzamanic/orchardizer

Comment: It's only the VS gallery too :) https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6408f2a0-ddb0-4fa1-938e-eef0f3ff73a3 I should probably add a link from the GitHub page to the gallery too...